# Definition of a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Whilst studying ring theory I came across the following definition of a prime:

Given a ring $R$ we say that $r\in R \setminus \{{0}\}$ is prime if $r$ is not a unit, and $r|xy$ implies that $r|x$ or $r|y$.

Does this in fact mean that in $\mathbb R$ a number like $3$ is not a prime? Because it is a unit due to it's inverse $\frac{1}{3}$ being in $\mathbb R$?

Now let's say we are in the ring $\mathbb Z$ and we have $r=6$. Now, $6$ is not a unit in $\mathbb Z$ because it's inverse $\frac{1}{6} \notin \mathbb Z$. But does $6|42$ not imply that $6|6$ or $6|7$? In which case $6$ would be a prime? Common sense tells me this is incorrect and somewhere along the way I have misunderstood something.

Could anyone clarify/explain what is going on here please?

Comment: But $42 = 3\cdot 14$, and $6\nmid 3$ and $6\nmid 14$.

Comment: Yes, 3 is not prime in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, 6 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ because $6 \mid 6$, but $6\nmid 3$ and $6\nmid 2$. The condition must hold *for all* pairs $\{x,y\}$ for the element $r$ to be prime.

Comment: “Now, $6$ is *not* a unit in $ℤ$” is what that should read.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ is not prime in $\mathbb R$.
 Although $6$ is not unit, but it also is not prime in $\mathbb Z$, because the $x$ and $y$ in your definition are arbitrary; you can not choose them.

Answer (score 1):

There are no primes in $\Bbb R$, since every non zero element is an unit.

The number $3$ is not an unit in $\Bbb Z$ because $\frac13\notin\Bbb Z$.

The number $6$ is not a prime in $\Bbb Z$, because there exist two integers $x$ and $y$ such that $6\mid xy$ but $6$ does not divide $x$ or $y$. Take for example $x=3$, $y=4$.